# What is the best way to get a derived status column based on existing result

Tags: sql, join, switch-statement, query-optimization, status

I have a table :

```
------------------------
testId |    runId   |result 
------------------------
**1    | 11         |0**
**1    | 12         |1**
**1    | 13         |1**
**1    | 14         |1**
**2    | 21         |0**
**3    | 31         |1**
**4    | 41         |1**
**4    | 42         |1**
**4    | 43         |1**
**5    | 51         |0**
**5    | 52         |0**
**5    | 53         |0**
**6    | 61         |1**
**6    | 62         |0**
**6    | 63         |1**
```

---

For a test there can be multiple run/execution. Each run have a result. here for result column, 0 is fail and 1 is pass.
I want to query
--if all the run PASS for test, the OverallStatus is PASS
--If all the run Faile for a test, the OverallStatus is FAIL
--If some of them pass and some of them fialed then OverallStaus is DEFECT

### I want to get an output from the above table like

### testId |numOfRun  |OverallStatus

**1    | 4        |Defect**

**2    | 1        |FAIL**

**3    | 1        |PASS**

**4    | 3        |PASS**

**5    | 3        |FAIL**

**6    | 3        |Defect**

---

---

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
select testId,
       numOfRun,
case when numOfRun = pass then 'pass'
    when numOfRun = fail then 'fail'
    else 'defect'
    end as OverallStatus 
from (
    select testId,
    count(*) numOfRun,
    sum(case when result = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as fail,
    sum(case when result = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as pass
    from table
    group by testId 
) t
```

Comment: Thanks. the solution works for me perfectly,  But I was wondering what would be the performance impact for table with around a million rows in a web project.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this in a single step:

```
select testid,
       (case when min(result) = 1 then 'Pass'
             when max(result) = 0 then 'Fail'
             else 'Defect'
        end) as overall_status
from t
group by testid;
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment:

```
select testid,
       (case when min(result) = N'TestSuccess' then 'Pass'
             when max(result) = N'TestFailure' then 'Fail'
             else 'Defect'
        end) as overall_status
from t
group by testid;
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood the smart trick here. But In my actual table the result is nvarchar and stored like 'TestSuccess', 'TestFailure'.

Comment: @rasoo . . . You accepted an answer that is incorrect, then, because your question is not correct.  But the idea is easily adapted to your strings.

Comment: .I already mentioned your answer is smarter than the previous and definitely your answer is more efficient. But You cannot say the other answer is wrong. Well, somehow the previous answer is acceptable for my case.